# What thread competition infulence？

Tags: multithreading

As you see,when I remove mt.lock() and mt.unlock，the result is smaller than 50000.

Why?What actually happens? I will be very grateful if you can explain it for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
class counter{
public:
    mutex mt;
    int value;
public:
    counter():value(0){}
    void increase()
    {
        //mt.lock();                                                                                                                                                                           
        value++;
        //mt.unlock();
    }
};

int main()
{
    counter c;
    vector<thread> threads;
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
        threads.push_back(thread([&]()
                                 {
                                    for(int i=0;i<10000;++i){
                                        c.increase();
                                    }
                                 }));
    }
    for(auto& t:threads){
        t.join();
    }
    cout << c.value <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`++` is actually two operations. One is reading the value, the other is incrementing it. Since it isn't an atomic operation, multiple threads operating in the same region of code will get mixed up.

As an example, consider three threads operating in the same region without any locking:

1. Threads 1 and 2 read `value` as `999`
2. Thread 1 computes the incremented value as `1000` and updates the variable
3. Thread 3 reads `1000`, increments to `1001` and updates the variable
4. Thread 2 computes incremented value as `999 + 1 = 1000` and overwrites 3's work with with `1000`

Now if you were using something like the ["fetch-and-add"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add) instruction, which *is* atomic, you wouldn't need any locks. See [`fetch_add`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add)